# Hadoop: Diagnose long running job

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

I need help with diagnosing why a particular Job  in Jobtracker is long-running and workarounds for improving it.

Here is an excerpt of the job in question (please pardon the formatting):

```
Hadoop job_201901281553_38848                               

User: mapred                                

Job-ACLs: All users are allowed                             
Job Setup: Successful                               
Status: Running                             
Started at: Fri Feb 01 12:39:05 CST 2019                                
Running for: 3hrs, 23mins, 58sec                                
Job Cleanup: Pending                                


Kind    % Complete  Num Tasks   Pending Running Complete    Killed      Failed/Killed
                            Task Attempts
map     100.00%     1177    0   0   1177    0   0 / 0

reduce  95.20%      12  0   2   10  0   0 / 0


Counter Map Reduce  Total               
File System Counters    FILE: Number of bytes read  1,144,088,621       1,642,723,691   2,786,812,312               
FILE: Number of bytes written   3,156,884,366   1,669,567,665   4,826,452,031               
FILE: Number of read operations 0   0   0               
FILE: Number of large read operations   0   0   0               
FILE: Number of write operations    0   0   0               
HDFS: Number of bytes read  11,418,749,621  0   11,418,749,621              
HDFS: Number of bytes written   0   8,259,932,078   8,259,932,078               
HDFS: Number of read operations 2,365   5   2,370               
HDFS: Number of large read operations   0   0   0               
HDFS: Number of write operations    0   12  12              
Job Counters    Launched map tasks  0   0   1,177               
Launched reduce tasks   0   0   12              
Data-local map tasks    0   0   1,020               
Rack-local map tasks    0   0   157             
Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms) 0   0   4,379,522               
Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)  0   0   81,115,664              
Map-Reduce Framework    Map input records   77,266,616  0   77,266,616              
Map output records  77,266,616  0   77,266,616              
Map output bytes    11,442,228,060  0   11,442,228,060              
Input split bytes   177,727 0   177,727             
Combine input records   0   0   0               
Combine output records  0   0   0               
Reduce input groups 0   37,799,412  37,799,412              
Reduce shuffle bytes    0   1,853,727,946   1,853,727,946               
Reduce input records    0   76,428,913  76,428,913              
Reduce output records   0   48,958,874  48,958,874              
Spilled Records        112,586,947  62,608,254  175,195,201             
CPU time spent (ms)    2,461,980    14,831,230  17,293,210              
Physical memory (bytes) snapshot    366,933,626,880 9,982,947,328   376,916,574,208             
Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot 2,219,448,848,384   23,215,755,264  2,242,664,603,648               
Total committed heap usage (bytes)  1,211,341,733,888   8,609,333,248   1,219,951,067,136               
AcsReducer  ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   3,284,862   3,284,862               
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   3,285,695   3,285,695               
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   3,284,862   3,284,862               
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   129,653 129,653             
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   129,653 129,653             
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   129,653 129,653             
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   129,653 129,653             
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   517,641 517,641             
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   23,786  23,786              
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   594,872 594,872             
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   597,739 597,739             
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   595,665 595,665             
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   36,101,345  36,101,345              
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   11,791  11,791              
ColumnDeletesOnTable-   0   11,898  11,898              
ColumnDeletesOnTable-0  176 176             
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   224,044 224,044             
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   224,045 224,045             
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   224,044 224,044             
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   17,425  17,425              
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   17,425  17,425              
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   17,425  17,425              
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   17,425  17,425              
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   459,890 459,890             
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   23,786  23,786              
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   105,910 105,910             
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   107,829 107,829             
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   105,909 105,909             
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   36,101,345  36,101,345              
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   11,353  11,353              
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   11,459  11,459              
RowDeletesOnTable-  0   168 168             
WholeRowDeletesOnTable- 0   129,930 129,930             
deleteRowsCount 0   37,799,410  37,799,410              
deleteRowsMicros    0   104,579,855,042 104,579,855,042             
emitCount   0   48,958,874  48,958,874              
emitMicros  0   201,996,180 201,996,180             
rollupValuesCount   0   37,799,412  37,799,412              
rollupValuesMicros  0   234,085,342 234,085,342
```

As you can see its been running almost 3.5 hours now. There were 1177 Map tasks and they complete some time ago. The Reduce phase is incomplete at 95%.
So I drill into the 'reduce' link and it takes me  to the tasklist. If I drill into the first incomplete task, here it is:

```html
Job job_201901281553_38848           
           
           
           
All Task Attempts           
           
Task Attempts Machine Status Progress Start Time Shuffle Finished Sort Finished Finish Time Errors Task Logs Counters Actions
attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0  RUNNING 70.81% 2/1/2019 12:39 1-Feb-2019 12:39:59 (18sec) 1-Feb-2019 12:40:01 (2sec)   Last 4KB 60 
         Last 8KB  
         All
```

From there I can see the machine/datanode running the task so i ssh into it and I look at the log  (filtering on just the task in question)
from  datanode $/var/log/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-mapred-tasktracker-.log

```html
2019-02-01 12:39:40,836 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2019-02-01 12:39:40,838 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 which needs 1 slots
2019-02-01 12:39:40,838 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 21 and trying to launch attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 which needs 1 slots
2019-02-01 12:39:40,925 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: Writing commands to /disk12/mapreduce/tmp-map-data/ttprivate/taskTracker/mapred/jobcache/job_201901281553_38848/attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0/taskjvm.sh
2019-02-01 12:39:41,904 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201901281553_38848_r_-819481850 given task: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0
2019-02-01 12:39:49,011 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.09402435% reduce > copy (332 of 1177 at 23.66 MB/s) >
2019-02-01 12:39:56,250 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.25233644% reduce > copy (891 of 1177 at 12.31 MB/s) >
2019-02-01 12:39:59,206 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.25233644% reduce > copy (891 of 1177 at 12.31 MB/s) >
2019-02-01 12:39:59,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.33333334% reduce > sort
2019-02-01 12:40:01,599 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.33333334% reduce > sort
2019-02-01 12:40:02,469 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.6667039% reduce > reduce
2019-02-01 12:40:05,565 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.6667039% reduce > reduce
2019-02-01 12:40:11,666 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.6668788% reduce > reduce
2019-02-01 12:40:14,755 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.66691136% reduce > reduce
2019-02-01 12:40:17,838 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.6670001% reduce > reduce
2019-02-01 12:40:20,930 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.6671631% reduce > reduce
2019-02-01 12:40:24,016 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201901281553_38848_r_000000_0 0.6672566% reduce > reduce
```

.. and  these lines repeat in this manner  for hours..
^ so it appears the shuffle/sort phase went very quick but after that,  its just the reduce phase crawling, the percentage is slowly increasing but takes  hours before the task completes.

1) So that looks like the bottleneck here- am I correct in identifying the cause of my long-running job is because this task (and many tasks like it) is taking a very long time on the reduce phase for  the task?

2) if so, what are my options for speeding it up?

Load appears to be reasonably low on the datanode assigned that task, as well as its iowait:

```html
top - 15:20:03 up 124 days,  1:04,  1 user,  load average: 3.85, 5.64, 5.96
Tasks: 1095 total,   2 running, 1092 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.8%us,  1.5%sy,  0.9%ni, 93.6%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   503.498G total,  495.180G used, 8517.543M free, 5397.789M buffers
Swap: 2046.996M total,    0.000k used, 2046.996M free,  432.468G cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
82236 hbase     20   0 16.9g  16g  17m S 136.9  3.3  26049:16 java
30143 root      39  19  743m 621m  13m R 82.3  0.1   1782:06 clamscan
62024 mapred    20   0 2240m 1.0g  24m S 75.1  0.2   1:21.28 java
36367 mapred    20   0 1913m 848m  24m S 11.2  0.2  22:56.98 java
36567 mapred    20   0 1898m 825m  24m S  9.5  0.2  22:23.32 java
36333 mapred    20   0 1879m 880m  24m S  8.2  0.2  22:44.28 java
36374 mapred    20   0 1890m 831m  24m S  6.9  0.2  23:15.65 java
```

and a snippet of iostat -xm 4:

```html
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.15    0.92    0.30    0.17    0.00   96.46

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00   350.25    0.00   30.00     0.00     1.49   101.67     0.02    0.71    0.00    0.71   0.04   0.12
sdb               0.00     2.75    0.00    6.00     0.00     0.03    11.67     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdd               0.00     9.75    0.00    1.25     0.00     0.04    70.40     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdf               0.00     6.50    0.00    0.75     0.00     0.03    77.33     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdg               0.00     5.75    0.00    0.50     0.00     0.02   100.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdc               0.00     8.00    0.00    0.75     0.00     0.03    93.33     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdh               0.00     6.25    0.00    0.50     0.00     0.03   108.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdi               0.00     3.75   93.25    0.50     9.03     0.02   197.57     0.32    3.18    3.20    0.00   1.95  18.30
sdj               0.00     3.50    0.00    0.50     0.00     0.02    64.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdk               0.00     7.00    0.00    0.75     0.00     0.03    82.67     0.00    0.33    0.00    0.33   0.33   0.03
sdl               0.00     6.75    0.00    0.75     0.00     0.03    80.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdm               0.00     7.75    0.00    5.75     0.00     0.05    18.78     0.00    0.04    0.00    0.04   0.04   0.03
```

```html
@<machine>:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        40G  5.9G   32G  16% /
tmpfs           252G     0  252G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       488M  113M  350M  25% /boot
/dev/sda8        57G  460M   54G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda7       9.8G  1.1G  8.2G  12% /var
/dev/sda5        40G   17G   21G  45% /var/log
/dev/sda6        30G  4.4G   24G  16% /var/log/audit.d
/dev/sdb1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk1
/dev/sdc1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  49% /disk2
/dev/sdd1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk3
/dev/sde1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk4
/dev/sdf1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk5
/dev/sdi1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk6
/dev/sdg1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk7
/dev/sdh1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk8
/dev/sdj1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk9
/dev/sdk1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk10
/dev/sdm1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk11
/dev/sdl1       7.2T  3.3T  3.6T  48% /disk12
```

This is version Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.0. Its highly-available with 3 zookeeper nodes, 2 namenodes, and 35  datanodes. YARN is not installed. Using hbase, oozie. Jobs mainly come in via Hive and HUE.

Each datanode has 2 physical cpus,  each with 22 cores. Hyperthreading is enabled.

If you need more information, please let me know. My guess is maybe I need more reducers, there are mapred-site.xml settings that need tuning,  perhaps the input data from map phase is too large, or Hive query needs written better. Im fairly new administrator to Hadoop, any detailed advice is great.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your query and it's plan

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It appears this job did not come in via Hive, but from a coordinated  Oozie  workflow so I  have no query plan or query to provide here.  Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide here.